# UnknownHostException in Grails application using liberty server

Tags: java, grails, log4j, websphere-liberty

I am getting below error in my Liberty message log file when I am trying to use Log4j in my Grails application. When I am run my application as locally, everything is working correctly but when I upload my application on to Liberty Server then I am seeing below error on log file. Please give me suggestion how I can resolve this issue. Thanks

```
[WARNING ] CWOBJ0210W: The transport type of the remote server on tvma1222.server.xxx.net:4809,tvma1223.server.xxx.net:4809,tvma1224.server.xxx.net:4809 cannot be determined. The following exception occurred while determining the transport type: java.net.UnknownHostException: tvma1224.server.xxx.net
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1412)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1316)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1239)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1189)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.naming.DetermineTransport$1.run(DetermineTransport.java:292)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.naming.DetermineTransport$1.run(DetermineTransport.java:288)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.naming.DetermineTransport.probe(DetermineTransport.java:288)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.naming.LocationServiceFactory$1.call(LocationServiceFactory.java:1451)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.naming.LocationServiceFactory$1.call(LocationServiceFactory.java:1447)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:809)
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.net.UnknownHostException: tvma1224.server.xxx.net

Seems pretty clear that the server where the code is running can't lookup tvma1224.server.xxx.net w/ the system resolver.  If you can't fix DNS, add an entry to /etc/hosts or the equivalent.

Comment: can you please guide me how I can add an entry?